# Removing tints on html using pixijs

Tags: java, html, pixi.js

I am trying to remove tints on canvas
i used pixijs to add tints and webgl animation

i tried change in pixi js code but its not working actually js is sophisticated can not find actual code where from tint is coming

```
#canvasid{
opacity: 0!important;
}
```

this style property removes tint but also removes my images
please help me
please check this link
https://team.redcollar.digital/